# NSDate - dateFromString is returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have an `NSString` that has a date. I'm trying to convert that date to an `NSDate`. When I do that I get `nil` fro the `NSDate`. Here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSLog(@"dateString = %@ date = %@", dateString, date);
```

Here is the output of the `NSLog`:

> `dateString = 2015-06-16 date = (null)`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format does not match the date string. It needs to be: :@"yyyy-MM-dd"

The order and other characters need to match.
yyyy for a four digit year
MM for a two digit month
dd for a two digit day

See: [ICU Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

Note: `NSLog()` uses the `NSDate` `description` method which presents date/time referenced to GMT (UTC) and `NSDateFormatter` defaults to your timezone so the date displayed may be different.